# Custom page load report

Tags: google-analytics

I'm just starting out with Google Analytics. Im trying to create a report that can give me data close to the graph below. How do I go about doing this?

These are the regexes that Im trying to track:

1. /
2. /abc/?  -  ie, trailing slash optional
3. /abc/.*  - ie, average of any urls under the folder "abc"

I know this is a complicated report, and might not be possible in Google Analytics out of the box, but anything that gets me close to this is also appreciated.

[image: Example grpah]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make a custom report with filters?  This [article](http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/03/28/understanding-google-analytics-custom-reports/) may help.

I have created a 3rd party service called [embeddedanalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  With it you can define charts against your GA data and then display them anywhere on a website.  We support filtering so you could generate a report such as this.  But generally speaking the filtering is not documented.  So if you are interested please drop us a note asking how to apply filters.